# how to find the transaction revert reason

Tags: etherscan, bsc

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bnb/0x0a15f861671369164bc132ad35c9c1128e9fdcd8dc472f706b8c3e1eaf8640db?trace=0.4.2

gas is ok , balance is ok , any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to swap WBNB and HUT token, but the router `0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d` doesn't have such pair.

The following code fails because `pair` is set to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Then the next call `pair.getReserves()` reverts because the target (pair) is not a contract.

```
        (address input, address output) = (path[i], path[i + 1]);
        (address token0,) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(input, output);
        IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, input, output));
        uint amountInput;
        uint amountOutput;
        { // scope to avoid stack too deep errors
        (uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = pair.getReserves();
```

Comment: yeah , I got the router address wrong